# VBA equivalent of System.Type.Missing parameter value

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I  am playing around with Outlook Add-Ins and Macros. In the Add-In, I have a C# routine that returns all of my Appointments for a given date range.

Note the following line

```
calItems.Sort("[Start]", System.Type.Missing);
```

from the routine:

```
    private Items GetAppointmentsInRange(MAPIFolder folder, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        string filter = "[Start] >= '" + startTime.ToString("g") + "' AND [End] <= '" + endTime.ToString("g") + "'";

        var calItems = folder.Items;
        calItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
        calItems.Sort("[Start]", System.Type.Missing);
        Items restrictItems = calItems.Restrict(filter);
        return restrictItems;
    }
```

I tried to rewrite it in VBA but I am unsure how to pass the System.Type.Missing param. If I comment out the line, the results aren't just unsorted, I get more rows back. I have no idea what filter is being used then.

```
Private Function GetAppointmentsInRange(folder, startTime, endTime)

        Dim filter As String

        filter = "[Start] >= '" & _
                  startTime & _
                  " 12:00 AM' AND [End] <= '" & _
                  endTime & " 11:59 PM'"


        Dim calItems
        Set calItems = folder.Items
        calItems.IncludeRecurrences = False
        'calItems.Sort "[Start]", System.Type.Missing
        calItems.Sort "[Start]"
        Dim restrictItems

        Set restrictItems = calItems.Restrict(filter)

        If (restrictItems.Count > 0) Then
            Set GetAppointmentsInRange = restrictItems
        Else
            Set GetAppointmentsInRange = Nothing
        End If

End Function
```

The C# code works. How do I replicate the System.Type.Missing code line in VBA?

Comment: I think it's a boolean value. True for descending, False for ascending. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866960.aspx

Comment: If you are getting back more results than you expect, it's likely the filter string. See here for an example on how to do this in VBA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867729.aspx

Comment: Try calItems.Sort "[Start]"